# Fronting of helping verbs for impossible probabilities

Tags: word-order, subjunctive-mood, sentence-patterns, subject-verb-inversion

This is  from 'Landour Days' by Ruskin Bond where he dwells at length on writings by hand.

" A few years earlier, when Dickens and Balzac had submitted their hefty manuscripts in longhand, no one had objected. Had their handwriting been awful, their manuscripts would still have been read".

It is often found for unreal probabilities in a past event helping verbs like had, were and should are inverted  or fronted to capture conditional " IF ".  Under normal conditions with 'if' the structure is canonical.

- If he had taken a little longer to get the load down, he might have been crushed under it.

Other examples:

- Shoud you see Kate, say Hi from me.
- Were I the Lord of Tatary, I would make my throne of beaten gold.

When and how did this sort of fronting of auxiliaries/ copular verbs come into being? Do they capture yes-no-polarity of interrogation embodied in IF particle.

Comment: Your second sentence with *Did* is ungrammatical.

Comment: Do you mean Balzac?

Comment: "**Had he taken** a little longer to get the load down, he might have been crushed under it" rather.

Comment: Please let us know about your background efforts to find an answer to this interesting question, to help us help you.

Comment: The counterfactual ("if") follows similar structure of inversion as an interrogative.

Comment: I have come across such construction as this with DID. If possible I would provide an authoritative example.

Comment: Though emphatic polarity is compatible with conditional clauses so far as emphatic DO is concerned and for which it is inserted and inverted, I have not found any ready example of ' do' being used omitting ' if' . The question is suitably amended in line with Kris' suggestions. We would like to know omission of 'if' for had, were, and should.

Comment: Are you asking how “Had their handwriting been awful…” compares to “(Even) If their handwriting had been awful…” or what, please?

Comment: Exactly so. How does question like inversion of helping verb serve the purpose of subordination and how has this  come into being?

Comment: The inversions with the verb are semantically equivalent to the versions with if. Is that more complicated than this?

Comment: You’re actually asking the wrong question here. Most other Germanic languages maintain the earlier situation, that the past subjunctive of _any_ verb can be fronted and subsume the semantic role of an irreal _if_ construction. Nobody knows when and how this came into being—it presumably happened some time Proto-Indo-European and Proto-Germanic, long before our earliest written sources. The interesting question as far as English specifically is concerned is when and how this system was _restricted_ to work with only certain modals and auxiliaries.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant definition of "have" in the OED is:

> In the protasis of a counterfactual conditional sentence, with inversion of subject and verb instead of an if-clause.
>
> <sub>The past subjunctive of have as a main verb is sometimes similarly used; cf. quots. OE2 at sense 5b, 1550 at sense 5b, 1957 at sense 1a.</sub>
>
> <sub>In quot. lOE   in a hypothetical clause with concessive force (see never adv. 4a).</sub>

The late Old English quotation is:

> Nan man ne dorste slean oðerne man, næfde he næfre swa mycel yfel gedon wið þone oðerne.

In the quote "næfde" is a contraction of the negative particle "[ne](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne#Old_English)" + *had*, "he" is obviously *he*, and "næfre" is *never*. So "næfde he næfre" is the relevant part of the sentence here.

[This source](https://books.google.com/books?id=F7Q1DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA103) translates the entire sentence as follows:

> And no man dared kill another man, no matter what great evil he might have done the other.

Another quotation from the OED is this one from 1250:

> Hefdich ȝare so idon, me stode betere þen me deð.
>   <sub>[Old English homilies and homiletic treatises (Sawles warde, and Pe wohunge of Ure Lauerd: Ureisuns of Ure Louerd and of Ure Lefdi, &c.) of the twelfth and thirteenth centuries](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/AHA2688.0001.001/1:3.22?rgn=div2;view=fulltext)</sub>

In this quote, "hefdich" is a combination of *had* + *ich* (i.e. the personal pronoun *I*), "ȝare" is [yore](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED54029&egs=all&egdisplay=open) (meaning *earlier*), "idon" is *done*. I would translate the start of this quote as "had I done so earlier". (The full sentence, according to [this source](https://books.google.com/books?id=07FhOYIfnccC&pg=PA244&lpg=PA244), can be translated as "if I had done so promptly, I would be in a better position".)

---

As for the reason why, I'm not sure. If I had to guess, I'd say it's because Old English had a pretty loose word order (I heard it's similar to modern-day German word order).

Comment: Oh wait. The OP is expected to do that much homework, though.

Comment: +1 for ye olde English. (but I'll be having nightmares not knowing how that last sentence ended. "If I had done so earlier... ")

Comment: @SConroy After searching some more, I found a source that translates the entire sentence as "if I had done so promptly, I would be in a better position". So it looks like you'll be having different nightmares ;)